# UCC API to UCMA 3.0 for Lync

Tags: lync, ucma, uccapi

I have a project written for LCS that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.UccApi.DLL, now I'm going to rework by changing the UCCAPI COM for C++ to UCMA 3.0 with the .tlb file generated from Microsoft.RTC.Collaboration.dll (interop from managed dll to native), so I wonder are there any examples or SampleApps written by C++ that I could look for?

I'm trying with using namespace Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration, it didn't work

The size of ".tlb" file is only 2k (generated from 5M .dll), so I'm not sure that it'll work

any advises?

Many thanks

Comment: Be sure to accept Paul's answer if it helped as a courtesy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating from UCCAPI to UCMA 3.0 will not be straightforward at all - the two object models are completely different, and target different platforms (UCCAPI is generally used client-side, UCMA is server side). I'm sure you will end up having to rewrite the logic that uses LCS/Lync functionality completely.

One option would be to keep using UCCAPI - it is still supported against Lync, although it will be deprecated for the next version (see the support notice [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ucclientsdk/thread/8b113669-b65b-4504-9118-d37eb8ea6572))

If you want to go with the newer APIs then I suspect your app will be a rewrite, but worth it in the long term. First decide whether to go down the Lync API route (for client-side apps) or the UCMA 3.0 route (for mid-tier server side apps).

If you're rewriting the app completely and have C# skills, then using C# would be the recommended route. Otherwise, is managed C++ an option? Failing that, you could wrap the chosen Lync API and expose it to COM to call it from your existing app.